# How to get the value of a specific element in a div when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a search engine program. People can ask questions and it will be listed in a different div. People can then click a question listed to answer it, and the answer (and that particular question) will be listed in another div.

But my code only shows the last question entered in the answer list. So if there are 3 questions and a user answered the first one, the expected output is:

```
Question 1?
Ans: Answer 1
```

But the actual output is:

```
Question 3?
Ans: Answer 1
```

```js
function separate()
 {
    var question = document.createElement("p");
    question.innerHTML = document.getElementById("qInput").value;
    document.getElementById("stackDisplay").appendChild(question);
    question.addEventListener("click", answerBox);
 }

 function answerBox(ques)
 {
    document.getElementById("answerBox").style.display = "block";
 }

 var i =1;
 function collectAns() {
    if(event.key === 'Enter') {
        var quest = document.getElementById("qInput").value;
        var ans = document.getElementById("ansSpace").value;
        document.getElementById("ansDisplay").innerHTML += i+") "+quest+"<br> Ans: "+ans+"<br><br>";
        document.getElementById("answerBox").style.display = "none";
        i+=1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" id="qInput">
    <button type="submit" onclick="separate()">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="stack">
    <span id="stackDisplay">
        <center><b><u> LIST OF QUESTIONS</u></b></center>
        <button id="close" onmouseover="clo()"> &times; </button>
    </span>
    <button onmouseover="list()"> &#9776; </button>
</div>

<div class="ans">
    <span id="ansDisplay">
        <center><b><u> LIST OF ANSWERS</u></b></center>
        <button id="closeans" onmouseover="closeans()"> &times; </button>
    </span>
    <button onmouseover="listans()"> 
        <i class="fa fa-commenting-o"></i>
    </button>
</div>

<div id="answerBox">
    <center><b> Write your answer:</b></center>
    <button id="closeans" onmouseover="closeansbox()"> &times; </button>
    <textarea id="ansSpace" placeholder="Your answer here..." onkeydown="collectAns()"></textarea>
</div>
```

I know it's because of `var quest = document.getElementById("qInput").value;` so it only takes the last question, but I don't know what to write instead of this.

I tried adding `question.addEventListener("click", function(){collectAns(ques)});` in the `separate()` but it prints `undefined` instead of the question.

I tried adding `var q = document.getElementById("stackDisplay").children;` in the `collectAns()` but I don't know which question they'll click so I can't give the index, so I wrote `q[this]` when printing, and it still gives `undefined`.

What should I do to make it show the question? (without jquery or php if possible, just html, css, javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed unnecessary stuff to answer the question.
The idea is to call *collectAns* with the question as argument. To do that you can use the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/bind) method.

As you are adding eventListners, you will need to remove old ones to prevent them to be executed too. The difficulty to remove old ones is that you don't know their name, they are anonymous because of the use of bind. You could store them in an array but it is simplier to clone the node, which do not clone the eventlistners attached to it.

```js
function separate() {
  var question = document.createElement("li");
  question.innerHTML = document.getElementById("qInput").value;
  document.getElementById("stackDisplay").appendChild(question);
  question.addEventListener("click", answerBox);
}

function answerBox() {
  const answerbox = document.getElementById("answerBox");
  const question = this.innerText;
  answerbox.querySelector('.ques').innerText = question;

  // find textarea, clone it and remove it
  // this is to remove any eventListener from it.
  const textarea = answerbox.querySelector('textarea');
  const new_textarea = textarea.cloneNode();
  textarea.remove();

  // add new eventListner with question as parameter
  new_textarea.addEventListener('keydown', collectAns.bind(null, this.innerText));
  answerbox.appendChild(new_textarea);

  // display answer box
  answerbox.style.display = "block";
}

var i = 1;

function collectAns(ques) {

  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    var ans = document.getElementById("ansSpace").value;
    document.getElementById("ansDisplay").innerHTML += i + ") " + ques + "<br> Ans: " + ans + "<br><br>";
    document.getElementById("answerBox").style.display = "none";
    i += 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Question.." name="search" id="qInput">
  <button type="submit" onclick="separate()">
        add
    </button>
</div>

<h4>LIST OF QUESTIONS:</h4>
<ul id="stackDisplay"></ul>

<h4>LIST OF ANSWERS</h4>
<ul id="ansDisplay"></ul>

<div id="answerBox">
  <div>Write your answer to question "<span class="ques"></span>":</div>
  <textarea id="ansSpace" placeholder="Your answer here..."></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! I'm new to this though, can you please explain how `const question = this.innerText;` works? How can it gets the value of the question when it wasn't a parameter? Do you have any articles for `bind` (bcs I don't understand it's parameters)? Is `bind` jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: As you are entering answerBox from a event listener, `this` corresponds to the target. In this case the question tag you click on. `this.innerText` only keeps the text from the DOM node, discarding all the tags.
`bind` first argument is the value `this` will take within the listener. Every other argument are passed to the event listener function.